# Replace a column of a DataFrame with the another one base on columns of another DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have these dataFrames:

```
df_1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Color': ['Azul','Verde'],
}) 
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Palabra': ['a','b','c']
}) 
df_3 =df_1.merge(df_2,how='cross') 
df_3['Valor'] = 0 

df_4 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Color': ['Azul','Azul'], 
    'Palabra': ['a','c'], 
    'Valor': [1,2]
})
```

[image]

I want that df_3 has the values of the column 'Valor' if they exist in df_4. I'm trying the following merge:

```
df_5 =  pd.merge(df_3,df_4,how='left',left_on=['Color','Palabra'],
                    right_on=['Color','Palabra'])
```

But it gives me the following DF:

[image]

I want that the column 'Valor' looks like the column 'Valor_y' but I can´t seem to make it work. I would appreciate a help to make it look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you don't need to initiate a column `Valor` in `df_3`.

So remove the line `df_3['Valor'] = 0` and then do a outer merge:

```
df_4.merge(df_3, how='outer')
```

or if you don't want to remove the line that initiates the column `Valor` you can just do

```
df_4.merge(df_3.drop(columns='Valor'), how='outer')

   Color Palabra  Valor
0   Azul       a    1.0
1   Azul       c    2.0
2   Azul       b    NaN
3  Verde       a    NaN
4  Verde       b    NaN
5  Verde       c    NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

Right idea with the merge, just don't merge with the 'Valor' column on df_3.

```
df_3[['Color', 'Palabra']].merge(df_4, 
                                 how = 'left', 
                                 on = ['Color', 'Palabra']).fillna(0)
```

You can drop the `.fillna(0)` if you want the missing values to be NaN instead.

Alternatively, if you have a ton of columns and want to avoid using merge, which is kind of slow. You can convert df_4 to a dictionary and then map the it.

```
valor_dict = df_4.set_index(['Color', 'Palabra'])['Valor'].to_dict()
df_3['Valor'] = [valor_dict.get((col,pal), 0) 
                 for col, pal 
                 in zip(df_3.Color, df_3.Palabra)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [iloc](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to use only the **first 2 columns** of **df_3** in the merge:

```
df_5 =  pd.merge(df_3.iloc[:, :2],df_4,how='left',left_on=['Color','Palabra'],
                    right_on=['Color','Palabra'])
```

#### Output:

```
   Color Palabra  Valor
0   Azul       a    1.0
1   Azul       b    NaN
2   Azul       c    2.0
3  Verde       a    NaN
4  Verde       b    NaN
5  Verde       c    NaN
```